# Why my table size is not reduced?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

have two database(db1 and db2). t1 is table in one database (db1) and t2 is table in other database(db2). Tables t1 and t2 are equal. All databases are in SQL Server 2008.

Table t1 have 260000 rows. Total size (Data space and Index size) of table t1 is 440mb,

Table t2 is empty.

80000 rows were removed of table t1 and added to table t2 (t2 exist in database db2).

Now, total size of table t2 is 80mb but size of t1 is 438mb.

Why size of table t1 only 2mb reduced?

I shrink database db1 but the size of table t1 not reduced.

Now can I reduce the size of table t1?

Comment: How do you know of your table size?

Answer (score 1):

If the 80000 were distributed randomly throughout the clustering key in `t1`, then you may not have actually freed up many pages. You may need to rebuild/reorganise your clustered and non clustered indexes on `t1` if you want to free up any space.

Take this simple example where a table is populsted

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.T', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.T;

CREATE TABLE dbo.T 
(   
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, 
    Filler CHAR(1000),
    CONSTRAINT PK_T__ID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID)
);
INSERT dbo.T (Filler)
SELECT  TOP 100000 REPLICATE('|', 1000)
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b;


EXECUTE sp_spaceused @objname = N'dbo.T';

name    rows    reserved    data        index_size  unused
T       100000  114768 KB   114288 KB   440 KB      40 KB
```

Now delete 20,000 random rows and check again:

```
DELETE  t
FROM    (   SELECT  TOP 20000 ID
            FROM    dbo.T
            ORDER BY NEWID()
        ) AS t;

EXECUTE sp_spaceused @objname = N'dbo.T';

name    rows    reserved    data        index_size  unused
T       80000   114768 KB   114288 KB   440 KB      40 KB
```

You can see that this has not actually removed any of the data size despite getting rid of 20% of the data. If we rebuild the index to get rid of the fragmentation we will see a reduction in size:

```
ALTER INDEX PK_T__ID ON dbo.T REBUILD;

EXECUTE sp_spaceused @objname = N'dbo.T';           

name    rows    reserved    data        index_size  unused
T       80000   91664 KB    91432 KB    176 KB      56 KB
```

With the last one your milage may vary since it really depends on where the rows are deleted from as to how many pages are freed up, but hopefully you get the picture. You need to sort out the fragmentation if you need to free up space.

[MSDN recommends](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx) a rebuild for fragmentation over 30%, and reorganise for when it is between 5% and 30%. However, I have read on SQL Server Performance (website currently down so can't link) that due to the fact that the rebuild can take advantage of parallelism that it is actually more efficient to just do a rebuild all the time.

Answer (score -1):

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/05/03/sql-server-shrinkfile-and-truncate-log-file-in-sql-server-2008/

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [db1] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE WITH NO_WAIT
DBCC SHRINKFILE(db1, 1)
ALTER DATABASE [db1] SET RECOVERY FULL WITH NO_WAIT
GO
```

Try with this,

Comment: error : Msg 8985, Level 16, State 1, Line number 1
Could not locate file 'db1' for database 'db1' in sys.database_files. The file either does not exist, or was dropped.

Comment: replace db1 with your database name

Comment: run this query but not reduce size

Comment: The funny thing about the blog is that Pinal Dave says "Thanks for your email. I suggest you stop this practice. There are many issues included here, but I would list two major issues...".